# Punctuation in a bulleted list, title and description

Tags: lists, colons, technology, em-dashes, tech-writing

I'm making documention for a piece of software and I need to write multiple lists, namely menus and functions of the software.

Currently items are formatted this way:

```
    • File 
        ◦ New  – start a new or open an existing project
        ◦ Open – open an existing project
        ◦ Save – save the current project
    • Edit
        ◦ Rotate Left – rotate a selected block counterclockwise
        ◦ Rotate Right – rotate a selected block clockwise
```

**Question:**

What is the proper or what are proper ways of punctuation here? Is colon a proper substitution or there should be the em-dash as it is?

Comment: Many of the "Related" questions in the sidebar seem to help here. Could you have a look at those? You are asking too many questions at once. Also the last two are purely a matter of opinion. I'm going to put this on hold to allow you to look at the related questions. For your second question you may want to search on "Headline" or "Headlinese".

Comment: The main question is what stands between the name and the description in a compound bullet list. No list punctuation arrticles I found tackle this problem; there are either enumerations or simple bullet lists.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189703/use-of-dash-or-comma-in-bulleted-list) asks whether to use a dash or a comma; you ask whether to use a dash or a colon. It's the same question, just asked differently.

Comment: I picture an equal sign, New = Start a project. But why do New and Open both open an existing project?

Comment: Documentation style isn't really a language issue, it's a matter of common practice in the industry.

Comment: You want the style guide for the place you intend to publish. Such things will be different from one office to the next, even from one editor to the next in the same newspaper.  The only strong advice I can give is, do the same thing all the time.